# Filtering out chaotic noise from breathing sensor signal

Tags: noise, c#

I've got a signal from a respiratory sensor (chest strap, piezo sensor) and I need to extract (live) the breath-per-minute value. Now for a nice steady signal this is not such a problem, the problem occurs when unexpected noise enters the signal such as when the participant starts moving his torso and/or arms. Simply removing the signal introduced by the movements is not possible (like via high/low pass filter) as at least a part of the movement signal falls right into the expected range of the breathing. So I would like to detect breathing rates between 5 and 25 breaths per minute. Or wavelengths between 2.4-12 seconds (or 0.42 to 0.083Hz). The sensor is set to sample at 100Hz.

[image: raw] The first image (raw) shows the raw data. Horizontal axis is in ticks (each = 0.01s). As you can see the first 40 seconds or so the signal is reasonably okay. Then (between 45 and 60 seconds) arms where moved slowly. Then a short period of standing still (65-75s) and then the torso was rotated back and forth (80-95s), then a short period of standing still (95-115s) and finally (115-end) both arms and torso where moving (slowly).

[image: average] My first step is a moving average (second image - avg). The window is 1s long and overlaps by 0.5s, resulting a new averaged value every 0.5 seconds.

I'm using a peak and valley detection, plus a minimum size of the peak/valley and a minimum distance of a new peak/valley from the 'zero', to calculate the breaths-per-minute value. Obviously when the movements are present the signal frequency increases, but as at least a good part of the frequencies introduces by the movement fall within the allowed breathing rates, I'm at a loss of how to 'clean up' the signal further to get more accurate frequencies during any movements.

For reference I've included a third image (prc) with the breaths-per-minute plotted processed breath p min
[image]
Any suggestion is of course very welcome!

Marco

I looked into FFT, but a quick look seemed to indicate that my raw and averaged signals are not easily suited to use FFT. The range of frequencies it detects is huge. Alternative stuff like zero-crossing do not remove the issue.

Comment: Have you searched online? This is a problem that has been researched (and somewhat solved!) extensively